# Python implementation of YFilter

Tags: python

Is there implementation of [this](http://yfilter.cs.umass.edu/index.htm) (YFilter) as a python library or there any similar libraries like this to enable filtering and transformation for high-Volume XML message brokering. so as to implement [this](http://yfilter.cs.umass.edu/appint.htm) functionality in python.

Answer (score 0):

You may look to [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) (asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing) + [lxml](http://lxml.de/).